# Scraping a list of items with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape my school schedule from Visma Inschool. Since it's hosted locally on the school I have permission to do so.

I'm trying to make an info screen and I'm completely lost when it comes to grabbing the schedule.

With this code:

```js
async function getInfo() {
  // identify element
  const f = await page.$("[class='active Timetable-TimetableDays_day']")
  // obtain text
  const text = await (await f.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue()
  console.log("The day is: " + text)
}
```

I get the whole active day in one text, but I want it to be split up into different texts so I can grab the next item on the schedule list as well as the teacher's name and the classroom for the class.

I do not expect anything other than the output I am getting, because I don't know what DOM to search for.

Here is the website as HTML:

```html
<div data-v-36c1dfe8="" role="gridcell" class="active Timetable-TimetableDays_day"><h3 data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="sr-only"> 7 Avtaler, torsdag 14 desember </h3><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="Timetable-Items"><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 40px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 08:20 og slutter 09:05 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-0-135299254" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 08:20 og slutter 09:05" subjectcode="IKM1002" tttype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702538400" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135299254" block="" teachinggroupid="12459877" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 08:20 - 09:05 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Teknologiforståelse </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Undervisningstime </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 140px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 09:10 og slutter 09:55 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-1-135299255" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 09:10 og slutter 09:55" subjectcode="IKM1002" tttype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702541400" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135299255" block="" teachinggroupid="12459877" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 09:10 - 09:55 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Teknologiforståelse </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Undervisningstime </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 260px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Matematikk 1P-Y IM på rom E208. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 10:10 og slutter 10:55 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-2-135353441" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Matematikk 1P-Y IM på rom E208. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 10:10 og slutter 10:55" subjectcode="MAT1121" tttype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702545000" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135353441" block="" teachinggroupid="12459866" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(57, 57, 96); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 10:10 - 10:55 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E208 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Matematikk 1P-Y IM </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Undervisningstime </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 360px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Vikar. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 11:00 og slutter 11:45 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-3-135317780" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Vikar. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 11:00 og slutter 11:45" tttype="SUBSTITUTION" originaltype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702548000" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135317780" block="" teachinggroupid="12459773" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 11:00 - 11:45 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Vikar </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 510px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Vikar. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 12:15 og slutter 13:00 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-4-135317781" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Vikar. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 12:15 og slutter 13:00" tttype="SUBSTITUTION" originaltype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702552500" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135317781" block="" teachinggroupid="12459773" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 12:15 - 13:00 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Vikar </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 610px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 13:05 og slutter 13:50 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-5-135321756" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 13:05 og slutter 13:50" subjectcode="YFF4106" tttype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702555500" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="[object Object]" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135321756" block="" teachinggroupid="12459773" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 13:05 - 13:50 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Undervisningstime </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div><div data-v-45669d56="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="popup-container" style="top: 710px; left: 0%;"><div data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56=""><h4 data-v-36c1dfe8="" data-v-45669d56="" class="sr-only"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 13:55 og slutter 14:40 </h4><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="dialog" test-id="vs-Timetable-item-4-6-135321757" class="Timetable-TimetableItem Timetable-TimetableItem-m" role="button" aria-label="Se detaljer om Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 13:55 og slutter 14:40" subjectcode="YFF4106" tttype="LESSON" starttimeanddateunix="1702558500" readonlyitems="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" actionitems="[object Object]" teachername="Teacher" entityid="135321757" block="" teachinggroupid="12459773" data-v-45669d56="" style="border-left: 6px solid rgb(83, 237, 155); height: 90px; width: 100%;"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" aria-hidden="true" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-wrapper"><div data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-header"><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-hours"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-clock"></i> 13:55 - 14:40 </small><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-location"><i data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="far fa-map-marker"></i> E109 </small><!----></div><p data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-subject-name"> Yrkesfaglig fordypning vg1 </p><!----><small data-v-33d0fd5d="" class="Timetable-TimetableItem-type"> Undervisningstime </small><!----></div></div></div><!----></div></div><div data-v-3b0485ec="" data-v-36c1dfe8="" class="Timetable-TimetableNowLine" style="top: 546.633px;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting the top-level element wrapping all of the elements, select the inner item elements and map over them to extract data from each one, dipping into leaf nodes and attributes as appropriate:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const html = await fs.readFile("test.html", {
    encoding: "utf-8",
  });
  await page.setContent(html); // replace with goto
  const data = await page.$$eval(
    ".Timetable-TimetableItem",
    els =>
      els.map(el => {
        const text = s =>
          el
            .querySelector(`.TimeTable-TimetableItem-${s}`)
            .textContent.trim();
        return {
          header: el.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim(),
          label: el.getAttribute("aria-label"),
          subjectCode: el.getAttribute("subjectcode"),
          tttype: el.getAttribute("tttype"),
          entityId: el.getAttribute("entityid"),
          teachingGroupId: el.getAttribute("teachinggroupid"),
          startTimeAndDateUnix: el.getAttribute(
            "starttimeanddateunix"
          ),
          teacher: el.getAttribute("teachername"),
          hours: text("hours"),
          location: text("location"),
          name: text("subject-name"),
          type: text("type"),
        };
      })
  );
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    header: 'Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 08:20 og slutter 09:05 ',
    label: 'Se detaljer om Teknologiforståelse på rom E109. Undervisningstime. Starter 14. desember 2023 klokken 08:20 og slutter 09:05',
    subjectCode: 'IKM1002',
    tttype: 'LESSON',
    entityId: '135299254',
    teachingGroupId: '12459877',
    startTimeAndDateUnix: '1702538400',
    teacher: 'Teacher',
    hours: '08:20 - 09:05',
    location: 'E109',
    name: 'Teknologiforståelse',
    type: 'Undervisningstime'
  },
// ...
]
```

Before selecting, use something like

```js
await page.waitForSelector(".TimeTable-TimetableItem-hours");
```

to make sure the elements are there.

Tips:

- Generally speaking, avoid attribute selectors for classes like `[class='active Timetable-TimetableDays_day']`. These are hyper-rigid and brittle--if the order of the classes changes, or an additional class is added, it'll break. Instead, use `.active.Timetable-TimetableDays_day` which is more flexible, or even drop the `.active` if `.Timetable-TimetableDays_day` is already distinct.
- Avoid ElementHandles when possible. They're harder to code than `$$eval`, slower (more network calls to the browser) and can go stale between selection and property accesses.